# Why there is no enforcing body in validating contributions?

Tags: publications, ethics

In undergraduate or graduate courses, marks and remaining measures are awarded or attributed solely based on the work done by a student.

Even in team works, marks can be varied by checking the contribution of individual students.

But, coming to research, there are no rules or an enforcing body, which checks the individual contributions of all the authors mentioned in the paper. Why is it coming under ethics, but not enforcing?

Is it because of the reason that it is difficult to implement or infeasible to implement?

Comment: An increasing amount of journals seem to ask for listing author contributions (which is great in my opinion), but it is indeed never really validated. Great question! I would really like to hear an answer!

Comment: There are rules in place, they differ by convention in each field. The expectation is that professionals will act as professionals. Those that don't tend to be noticed and dealt with.

Comment: I'm really struggling to imagine any way of making this work in practice. 'Oh boy, another audit by the Author Police - yay!'

Comment: Who would do the audit? What would they base it on?

Comment: How would you do this, for example, for mathematics, in which the entire contribution of an author (who is making a major contribution) could well be delivered verbally?

Comment: Would this be another thing academics do for free and journals get to make money on?

Comment: "Have you tried using Gazpacho's theorem, instantiated by De Tortillones' homomorphism?" may turn a decade-long dead end into a viable proof. Is that worth co-authorship? How will you enforce its check? Seriously, one more bureaucratic exercise is what we just needed. Many of us scientist enter the field because of its freedoms and honour systems. If we are going to jump through yet increasing number of bureaucratic hoops, we can as well go to industry and get paid better for that.

Comment: +1000 for @CaptainEmacs comment! Organisations have a tendency to manage themselves to death rather than to get their work done. We certainly don't need more of this in academia.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the "enforcement mechanism" is the entire academic community. Papers, for the most part are written by specialists, often for other specialists. Every reader can make a judgement about both ethical concerns and contributions. Every reader can criticize any paper that they read.

One problem with a "centralized" scheme is that the expertise is so varied that it would take a gigantic organization to do so. That "gigantic organization" is the entire scholarly community.

Moreover, as to contributions by individuals in joint papers, that is probably best left to the authors themselves. Most journals insist on some form of agreement among authors in this by asking them all to "sign off" on the paper.

And your judgement about what is a "minor" contribution vs a "major" one might well differ from mine. But this is because there is so much variation in the kinds of contributions: time spent, "effort", key ideas, writing, organization, creation of the enabling lab, ...

Comment: +1 for "Actually the 'enforcement mechanism' is the entire academic community" - true for many of academia-related integrity questions. Should be in the FAQ.

Answer (score 6):

Buffy's answer is pretty spot on, but I think there is also the following question: *Why would we care about who did what?* We care about this for class projects because at some point, individual grades have to be assigned. But I see no particularly good reason why we need to decide once and for all that for a given paper, authors X, Y, and Z contributed 60, 30, and 10% of the work.

There is no reason to build a substantial administration for obtaining information nobody cares about.

Comment: In line with this answer, my impression is that the main purpose of "author contributions" sections of papers is not really to credit authors for the specific contributions they all made but rather to fight gift authorship and force the authors to state explicitly why they should all in fact be authors. Not sure how to back up that impression, though.

Comment: @BryanKrause I think that is true.